# In the Latin Rite of the Catholic Church, if a man becomes a widower, can he become a priest?

Tags: catholicism, marriage, priesthood, celibacy

If a husband man loses his wife to death, is it possible for him to become a Catholic priest in the Latin Rite? What about any children of this marriage union?

Can this man now become a priest in the Latin Rite and climb the priestly ladder (bishop, archbishop, ect)?

Comment: For example: Calvary (2014) https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2234003/

Comment: Okay got it. Out of curiosity, what if the man is a widower with children? Is it any different?

Comment: @LukeHill No, no difference.

Comment: @OneGodtheFather Yes, there is a difference. Children of a widower must be mature, independent and of majority. Widowers with young children must look after their families first and foremost in the eyes of God. The father of a family must support his children until they are on their own, before he even considers being a priest.

Comment: @KenGraham That's interesting - do you have a link to any official document regarding that?

Comment: @KenGraham That isn't true of children of married priests. Hmmm ...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**In the Latin Rite of the Catholic Church, if a man becomes a widower, can he become a priest?**

The short answer is: **Absolutely**

I know a priest in the Diocese of Tulsa, Oklahoma who became a permanent deacon and after the death of his wife, he went on to become an ordained Catholic priest. Just in passing right here, I would like to mention that permanent deacons can not get remarried at the death of their spouse.

Not only can widowers become priests, they may also (rarely) become bishops. Of course any children of the marriage must be grown up and self supporting.

One such case is about Bishop Jean-François de Hercé, Bishop of Nantes, France 1836-1849. Not only was he once married, he even had several daughters; one of them died due to complications in childbirth while he was the Bishop of Nantes.

Bishop Jean-François de Hercé had children also.

> Après le décès de sa femme fin 1820 et le mariage de sa fille Marie-Lucie avec Guillaume-François d'Ozouville Blason Guillaume-Francois d'Ozouville.svg en 1825, il est de nouveau attiré par le sacerdoce.
>
> II rentre au séminaire de la Congrégation de Saint-Pierre à Malestroit à l'âge de 54 ans, reçoit tous les ordres dans l'année 1830 y compris le sacerdoce, en la cathédrale de Rennes, le 18 décembre 1830. Désigné d'avance pour devenir curé de l'église de la Trinité à Laval, il est installé le 20 février 1831[1](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pope_Honorius_IV).
>
> Il refuse les évêchés de Saint-Brieuc, d'Orléans, de Vannes, mais cède aux instances de l'évêque de Nantes qui le demande pour coadjuteur. Sacré à Nantes le 17 avril 1836, il commence la visite du diocèse à pied, bravant la pluie et le soleil ("je suis fils d'Apollon", disait-il), s'attirant l'enthousiasme des populations. Polyglotte, il confessait dans plusieurs langues les étrangers que le commerce attirait à Nantes.
>
> La mort, le 12 mai 1838, de l'évêque Mgr de Guérines, le laisse titulaire du siège de Nantes.
>
> Article détaillé : Liste des évêques de Nantes.
> Plus que jamais il se dépense, réorganise les fabriques, et la caisse de retraites des ecclésiastiques, rétablit les conférences, allant prêcher jusqu'en Angleterre, où il convertit nombre de protestants. Il crée de nouvelles paroisses, fonde trois établissements de Frères des écoles chrétiennes, achète, pour en former un collège de plein exercice, le pensionnat de Saint-Stanislas, et préside aux travaux d'achèvement de la cathédrale. Sa popularité parmi les paroissiens n'empêche pas une partie de la population nantaise de se ruer sur l'évêché en février 1848. Sentant ses forces défaillir, Jean-François de Hercé démissionne de son poste le 29 novembre 1848 après avoir obtenu comme successeur l'abbé Jaquemet, vicaire général, qui avait accompagné l'archevêque de Paris Mgr Denys Affre sur les barricades à Paris.
>
> Il meurt le 31 janvier 1849, au terme d'une vie durant laquelle il aura pleinement réalisé sa triple vocation de père, de maire et d'évêque[5](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/09017a.htm).
>
> Mgr de Hercé avait par ailleurs vivement encouragé son gendre Guillaume-François d'Ozouville à se faire le promoteur (de 1842 à 1851) d'un évêché à Laval. Il entretenait dans le même sens une correspondance suivie avec Madame de Vaufleury, à laquelle il adressa le journal de son dernier voyage à Rome en 1846. Grâce à l'impulsion de Jean-François de Hercé et à l'opiniâtreté de Guillaume-François d'Ozouville, ce nouvel évêché fut créé en 1855. -[Jean-François de Hercé](https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Fran%C3%A7ois_de_Herc%C3%A9)

For those who can read French, I would recommend reading the book, ***Père, Maire, Evêque***. Bishop Jean-François de Hercé was an exceptional Catholic prelate.

[image: Bust of Bishop de Hercé. Chapelle of the Immaculate Conception at Nantes.]

Bust of Bishop de Hercé. Chapel of the Immaculate Conception at Nantes.

Even a few pope’s were widowers before entering Holy Orders.

Pope Hormisdas (450-523) is one example.

> Before becoming a deacon, Hormisdas was married and had a son, Silverius, who later became pope. During the Laurentian schism, Hormisdas was one of the most prominent clerical partisans of Pope Symmachus. He was notary at the synod held at St. Peter's in 502. Two letters of Magnus Felix Ennodius, bishop of Pavia, survive addressed to him, written when the latter tried to regain horses and money he had lent the Pope. - [Pope Hormisdas](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pope_Hormisdas)

[Pope Honorius IV](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pope_Honorius_IV) (1285-1287) is another example of a pope who entered the clergy after the death of his spouse.

> According to John Julius Norwich, he was the last pope to be married before ordination.

It is interesting to note that Pope Honorius IV became Pope a century after the Church imposed priestly celibacy in 1139 at the [Second Lateran Council](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/09017a.htm).